# Why am I getting an Invalid Hook Call on a netlify build, but not on local gatsby?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, netlify

I am tearing my hair out here...
Any advice or pointers in the correct direction would be much appreciated.

**Issue**

I have a deployed gatsby site using netlify.
Once built, one endpoint (site.com/posts/page/1) is completely blank. It is throwing the "Invalid Hook Call" error in the console, but *only* on netlify.
Interestingly, the deployed version of the page actually loads when you manually refresh.
Local build using gatsby build is fine, everything shows up as expected.

**What I've tried**
A lot of what I've been trying has been to try and replicate it locally and fix from there (to no success).

- locally: deleting all cache using gatsby clean, manually deleting node_modules, reinstalling with npm and building site. Can't replicate issue.
- locally: downgrading versions of packages back to the state when my site did work online. Can't replicate issue
- Netlify: Deleting cache and redeploying. Doesn't solve issues.

**Invalid Hook Call**

Ok, so my issues with trying to reproduce aside, I checked into possible reasons for the invalid hook call itself.

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

as far as I can tell, all of these seem to be fine?
Files below in case someone can spot something I can't...

---

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "gatsby-theme-flora-website-starter",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Oliver Bains @obains",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "gatsby develop",
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "clean": "gatsby clean"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "gatsby": "^2.29.3",
    "gatsby-cli": "^2.19.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-google-fonts": "^1.0.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.9.1",
    "gatsby-theme-flora-website": "^2.3.7",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "styled-components": "^4.4.1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/obains/flora-website-starter.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/obains/flora-website-starter/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/obains/flora-website-starterr#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.19.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0"
  }
}
```

---

In particular, the .js file which leads to the endpoint comes from "gatsby-theme-flora-website".

resultsAll.js

```js
import React from "react";
import path from "path";
import { graphql, navigate } from "gatsby";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import Card from "../components/Card";
import { Box, Grid, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import Pagination from "materialui-pagination-component";

const Posts = ({ posts, pathPrefix }) => {
  return (
    <Grid container spacing={3}>
      {posts.map(
        ({
          node: {
            excerpt,
            fileAbsolutePath,
            frontmatter: { id, title, featuredImage }
          }
        }) => {
          const postDate = path
            .basename(fileAbsolutePath)
            .split(".")
            .splice(0,1)
            .join(" ");
          return (
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={4} key={id}>
              <Card
                featuredImage={featuredImage}
                title={title}
                url={`/${pathPrefix}/${id}`}
                postDate={postDate}
                excerpt={excerpt}
              />
            </Grid>
          );
        }
      )}
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default function ResultsAllTemplate({
  data: {
    site: {
      siteMetadata: {
        templates: {
          posts: { pathPrefix }
        }
      }
    },
    allMdx: { edges: posts }
  },
  pageContext: { totalPages, currentPage }
}) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Box flexGrow={1} width="100%" maxWidth={960} marginX="auto">
        <Box padding={2}>
          <Posts posts={posts} pathPrefix={pathPrefix} />
          <Typography
            variant="caption"
            color="textSecondary"
            style={{ display: "block", marginTop: 32, marginBottom: 4 }}
          >
            Select page:
          </Typography>
          <Pagination
            selectVariant="tab"
            page={currentPage}
            totalPages={totalPages}
            onChange={page => navigate(`/${pathPrefix}/page/${page}`)}
          />
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </Layout>
  );
}

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query($skip: Int!, $limit: Int!) {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        templates {
          posts {
            pathPrefix
          }
        }
      }
    }
    allMdx(
      filter: { fileAbsolutePath: { regex: "/content/posts/" } }
      sort: { order: ASC, fields: [fileAbsolutePath] }
      limit: $limit
      skip: $skip
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          excerpt(pruneLength: 100)
          fileAbsolutePath
          frontmatter {
            id
            title
            featuredImage {
              childImageSharp {
                fluid(maxWidth: 720) {
                  ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

EDITS

The only hook in the project would be in the following file home.js which creates the homepage of the website, and doesn't throw the invalid hook error...

home.js

```js
import React from "react";
import path from "path";
import { Link, graphql } from "gatsby";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import Card from "../components/Card";
import { Box, Button, Grid, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import theme from "../style/theme";
import { useHasScroll } from "has-scroll-hook";

const Posts = ({ posts, pathPrefix }) => {
  return (
    <Grid container spacing={3}>
      {posts.map(
        ({
          node: {
            excerpt,
            fileAbsolutePath,
            frontmatter: { id, title, featuredImage }
          }
        }) => {
          const postDate = path
            .basename(fileAbsolutePath)
            .split(".")
            .splice(0,1)
            .join(" ");
          return (
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={4} key={id}>
              <Card
                featuredImage={featuredImage}
                title={title}
                url={`/${pathPrefix}/${id}`}
                postDate={postDate}
                excerpt={excerpt}
              />
            </Grid>
          );
        }
      )}
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default function HomeTemplate({
  data: {
    site: {
      siteMetadata: {
        subtitle,
        description,
        templates: {
          posts: { pathPrefix }
        }
      }
    },
    allMdx: { edges: posts }
  }
}) {
  /* Get the vertical scrollbar offset as a boolean value. */
  const hasScroll = useHasScroll();

  return (
    <Layout elevateAppBar={hasScroll}>
      <Box display="flex" flexDirection="column">
        <Box
          textAlign="center"
          paddingTop={1}
          paddingBottom={1}
          paddingX={8}
          style={{
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
            color: theme.palette.common.white,
            clipPath: "rectangle(0 0, 100% 60, 100% 0%, 0% 100%)",
            "-webkit-clip-path": "polygon(0 0, 100% 60, 100% 0%, 0% 100%)"
          }}
        >
          <Box flexGrow={1} marginX={"auto"} width="90%" marginBottom={4} marginTop={2}> 
            <Typography
              color="inherit"
              variant="h2"
              style={{
                position: "center",
                fontSize: "3rem",
                fontWeight: "500",
                letterSpacing: 2.5,
                fontFamily:
                  'Mulish', //  Work Sans, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Roboto, sans-serif
                marginBottom: 4
              }}
            >
              {subtitle}
            </Typography>
            <Typography color="inherit" variant="body1">
              {description}
            </Typography>
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </Box>
      <Box flexGrow={1} marginX="auto" width="100%" maxWidth={960}>
        <Box padding={4}>
          <Posts posts={posts} pathPrefix={pathPrefix} />
          {posts.length > 1 && (
            <Box
              display="flex"
              justifyContent="flex-end"
              padding={3}
              marginTop={1}
            >
              <Button
                variant="contained"
                outlined={
                  theme.palette.type === 'light' ? 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)' : 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.23)'}
                borderRadius={
                  theme.shape.borderRadius = "0%" }
                color="secondary"
                component={Link}
                to={`/${pathPrefix}/page/1`}
              >
                View All
              </Button>
            </Box>
          )}
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </Layout>
  );
}

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query($limit: Int!) {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        subtitle
        description
        templates {
          posts {
            pathPrefix
          }
        }
      }
    }
    allMdx(
      filter: { fileAbsolutePath: { regex: "/content/posts/" } }
      sort: { order: DESC, fields: [fileAbsolutePath] }
      limit: $limit
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          excerpt(pruneLength: 80)
          fileAbsolutePath
          frontmatter {
            id
            title
            featuredImage {
              childImageSharp {
                fluid(maxWidth: 720) {
                  ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Versions

Locally I'm running:
node 14.9.0
npm 6.14.8

I've set the environment variables on netlify to match these:
NODE_VERSION 14.9.0
NPM_VERSION 6.14.8

---

The only error thrown is this one from React, which I see when using the Console in Developer Tools / Inspect in Chrome:

```
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons: 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM) 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

Comment: What versions of node and npm you have set locally and what [in Netlify](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/manage-dependencies/)?

Comment: locally I'm running: node 14.9.0 and npm 6.14.8.

I've set the environment variables on netlify to match these:
NODE_VERSION
14.9.0
NPM_VERSION
6.14.8

Comment: Please put additional details in question, not in comments

Comment: Hi @rodby - It's a direct answer to your question. I can add it in the question too though.

Comment: It's odd, in the provided file you are not using hooks. Where are you using them?

Comment: Apologies for the delay in response, I'm adding an excerpt of the only hook used into my description.

Comment: Can you add the exact error message and stacktrace?

Comment: I've added the only error I get (which is the React error from inspecting the console in production).